# MSAccess- Update all the records from a textbox

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a textbox in a form that accepts a date and I have to update all the records in a table with the value in the textbox i.e, the same value shoul be updates in the date field of all the records ,..how to do it?

Comment: You just need to execute a query which will UPDATE the date field. So something like `UPDATE Table1 SET MyDate = [Forms]![Form1]![MyTextBox]`.

Comment: Where to use that query? I have a button in that form named as "Submit" If I click that button the value from the text box should be updated to the date field of all the records of the table.

Comment: Create the query as you usually would in Query Design (to do it in SQL create a new query and don't add any tables when it asks and then click the SQL button in the Design ribbon).  In the 'On Click' event code behind your button enter `DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName", acViewNormal` or another way is to not create the query and just enter the code `DoCmd.RunSQL "<SQL from my first comment>"` behind the button.

Comment: The button already performs a saverecord macro..How to make the button also run this query.

Comment: Remove the save macro and add VBA code instead.  `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` will save the record if it needs saving (an alternative is `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` which will save the record whether it needs saving or not), so put that as the first line.  Then put the `DoCmd.RunSQL...` as the second line.

Comment: Thank you it woked...But a warning appears saying that you're gonna update 10 rows ..you can't reverse it...Is there a way to make it not appear?

Comment: Add `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` before the `DoCmd.RunSQL` and `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to execute the update query with no warnings with just one line of code is to do the following:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE tblMyTableName SET MyDateFieldInQuestion=" & MyTextBoxName.Value & ";"`
```

CurrentDB.Execute does not display warnings so it is a little cleaner in my opinion.  That and you don't have to worry about forgetting to turn the warnings back on (which you will want) afterwards.